# Kerberos login from php

Tags: php, security, authentication, kerberos

I have made a login form in php and now I want to authenticate it with Kerberos. Does anyone know how to do it? I have been trying for quite some time now, but without any success.

Things that I have tried so far:

1. KADM5 PHP module. I read their manual from [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.kadm5.php) link. I am still stcuk on the installation step. It says to install the PECL extensions using the command:

```
$pecl install pecl_http
```

But it always shows this error:

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pecl_http"
install failed
```

I have installed all the packages that were listed in the manual.

2. LDAP:PHP module. This is the code that I have tried in PHP:

```
<?php  

    $ldaphost = <servername>;  
    $ldapport = 636;  
    $ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport) or die("Could not connect to ".$ldaphost);

    echo $ds;  

    if($ds) {

        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);  
        $username = $_GET["username"];  
        $upasswd = $_GET["password"];  
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ds, $username, $upasswd);  

        if($ldapbind) {
            print "Congratulations!";
        } else {
            print "Access Denied!";
        }

    } 

?>
```

When I run this script, I get this error:

> Resource id #4PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /var/www/joomla/scripts/testing.php on line 15
>       Access Denied!

Comment: Why are you wasting your time? Use something like `mod_auth_kerb`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, K5ADM has no "login" capabilities, so you can try with the "real" kerberos module
http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/phpkrb5/

I'm not sure if current version do compile. I did it a few years ago, and I did need to
apply the patch below, and didn't use makefile but

cc -DCOMPILE_DL_KRB5 -fpic -I. -I/usr/include/php
-I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/Zend
-I/usr/include/php/TSRM -c -o phpkrb5.o phpkrb5.c
cc -shared -rdynamic -o phpkrb5.so phpkrb5.o

```
Index: phpkrb5.c
===================================================================
RCS file: /sources/phpkrb5/phpkrb5/phpkrb5.c,v
retrieving revision 1.1
diff -r1.1 phpkrb5.c
23,24c23,24
< #include "php.h"
< #include "php_krb5.h"
---
> #include "main/php.h"
> #include "phpkrb5.h"
```